# Performing tasks concurrently

Tags: java, concurrency

I made a class to perform tasks concurrently and have implemented it. From appearances and testing, everything seems to work. How can I improve this? I understand this is somewhat a broad question, so please let me know how I should narrow it down.

Here is the pseudocode:

The general idea is a single `Starter` spawns multiple `TaskWorker` to do the work. I want to start the loading process fairly early on and then block EDT until the completion of all `TaskWorker`.

```
class ImproveMe {
  private AtomicInteger incompleteTasksCount = new AtomicInteger( -1 );
  /* SwingWorker has a limitation of 10 */
  private static final int MAX_CONCURRENT_THREAD = 20;
  private static ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( MAX_CONCURRENT_THREAD );

  /* This just starts multiple TaskWorker */
  class Starter extends SwingWorker {
    Object doInBackground() {
      incompleteTasksCount.getAndSet( -1 );

      Tasks[] taskList = getTasks();
      for ( Task task : taskList ) {
        /* Track incomplete tasks */
        if ( incompleteTasksCount.compareAndSet( -1, 1 ) {
          incompleteTasksCount.incrementAndget();
        }
        threadPool.submit( new TaskWorker( task ) );
      }
      threadPool.shutdown();
    }
  }

  /* Performs the actual work -- I don't care about the results since it will be cached elsewhere */
  class TaskWorker implements Runnable {
    Task t;
    TaskWorker( Task t ) {
      this.t = t;
    }

    void run() {
      if ( t != null ) {
        do stuff with 't'
      }

      synchronized( incompleteTasksCount ) {
        if ( incompleteTasksCount.decrementAndGet() == 0 ) {
          /* everything is done! */
          incompleteTasksCount.notifyAll();
        }
      }
    }
  }

  /* User will call this to start the loading */
  public void startLoading() {
    if ( !threadPool.isShutdown() ) {
      Starter s = new Starter();
      s.execute();
    }
  }

  /* User will call this to ensure that everything has complete before continuing */
  public void blockUntilDone() {
    boolean cont = true;
    if ( incompleteTasksCount.get() == 0 || threadPool.isTerminated() ) {
      return;
    } else if ( incompleteTasksCount.get() == -1 ) {
      /* not loaded/started */
      return;
    }

    while ( cont ) {
      synchronized( incompleteTasksCount ) {
        try {
          incompleteTasksCount.wait();
        } catch ( InterruptedException e ) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          cont = false;
        } finally {
          if ( incompleteTasksCount.get() == 0 ) {
            cont = false;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In reality, `TaskWorker` calls [`PrintService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html).[`getSupportedAttributeValues(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/print/PrintService.html#getSupportedAttributeValues%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.print.DocFlavor,%20javax.print.attribute.AttributeSet%29) because of the numerous printers and Java caches that so any future calls will return fairly quickly as compared to the first time (some of the network printers took 40+ seconds). I call `ImproveMe.startLoading()` somewhere fairly early in my program then before the actual program starts (e.g. GUI is shown), I use `ImproveMe.blockUntilDone()` to ensure everything is loaded.

Answer (score 3):

`SwingWorker` comes with all the control features you try to emulate here. It already uses an `ExecutorService` under the hood. I'm not sure why you want to increase the maximum pool size, but given that the code does not compile as given, makes me suspect you did not decide this, based on performance measuring.

So here's what I did :

1. Launching the workers is lightweight enough to not need
   to be run in a separate thread, so I inlined Starter.
2. Keeping tabs on task progression is done through the `Future` that you get from
   an `ExecutorService`. `SwingWorker` exposes this by implementing `Future`
   itself. Waiting until a `SwingWorker` is done is as simple as calling its
   `get()` method, which will block until the task is done.
3. You don't need the low level constructs `wait()` and `notifyAll()`.
4. Properly handle `InterruptedException` : put it in your throws clause, or if you catch
   it, reset the `Thread`'s interrupted flag by calling
   `Thread.currentThread().interrupt();` so clients of your code know the thread has been
   interrupted, and they can do their own cleanup.
5. `SwingWorker` uses generics to know the type of the result. Typically when no result is
   given, `Void` is chosen as a return type. (this makes a comment about not caring about
   the return value superfluous).
6. I've spent attention to the visibility modifiers, tightening it wherever possible,
   exposing only as much as is strictly needed.
7. `Future.get()` throws an ExecutionException if the underlying task execution
   threw an exception. Your code had no means of dealing with those.

Here's my refactoring of your code :

```
public class ImproveMe {
    private final List<SwingWorker> workers;

    public ImproveMe(Task[] tasks) {
        workers = new ArrayList<>(tasks.length);
        for (Task task : tasks) {
            workers.add(new TaskWorker(task));
        }
    }

    /* User will call this to start the loading */
    public void startLoading() {
        for (SwingWorker worker : workers) {
            worker.execute();
        }
    }

    /* User will call this to ensure that everything has complete before continuing */
    public void blockUntilDone() throws InterruptedException {
        for (SwingWorker worker : workers) {
            waitForWorker(worker);
        }
    }

    private void waitForWorker(SwingWorker worker) throws InterruptedException {
        try {
            worker.get(); // will block until the worker's task is done
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e); // more appropriate exception handling here
        }
    }

    private static class TaskWorker extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        private final Task t;

        TaskWorker( Task t ) {
            this.t = t;
        }

        public Void doInBackground() {
            if ( t != null ) {
                //do stuff with 't'
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `SwingWorker` maximum of 10 is actually not enough for me and it's also shared with whatever `SwingWorker` that could exist at that point and time - it did originally start out as a `SwingWorker`. (1) Yes, I've thought about getting rid of the `Starter` class but kept it around for future if I do care about the results it generates. (2) I suppose I can track number of complete via a series of `isDone()` call. (3), (4), and (5) are good points. (6) Just pseudocode but I'll pay attention to that when I include code in the future.

Comment: If you really must use more than 10 threads, you can replace `worker.execute()` by `service.execute(worker)`. But I'm not sure how you think you know you need more without actually measuring performance. (I hope you don't think that it is the maximum number of tasks)

Comment: BTW : [*Premature optimization is the root of all evil.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize)

Comment: In testing, I personally have 13 tasks. I have no idea what the average tasks size is going to be but I do not want to share the thread pool with `SwingWorker` nor do I want to create too many tasks at once hence why I have a fixed sized of threads that I'm using outside of `SwingWorker`. Some tasks returns in under a second and some takes more than 40 seconds to finish - it's unfortunately something that I can't control. Of course it's not the maximum number of tasks - it's the maximum number of concurrent tasks.

Comment: You may want to avoid sharing the pool (who else will submit tasks to it?) but you cannot avoid sharing memory and CPUs. In the end the overhead of your extra threads may harm performance rather than help it. That's why you should measure. That's really all I'm saying : measure before optimizing (and after, so you know it helped :) ).

Comment: Well, my code is just a small part in the system - I have no control of what others do with `SwingWorker` but as far as my tasks goes, there's only me.  It's hard to find the setup to measure since this is primarily dependent on the number of printers installed so I've been been going by rough estimates of my own results.